# Mathematica - printing a matrix, have fraction, want decimal to 6 places

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, decimal, fractions

Hi i am currently taking a Matrix, P, and doing this

```
     P500 = MatrixPower[P, 500];
```

and i print it back out with P500//MatrixForm
but many of the numbers are these HUGE fractions, and i want decimals to six places. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert `P` to machine numbers before exponentiation:

```
MatrixPower[N[P], 500]
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Szabolcs said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9720925/198315), first you need to use `N` to convert to decimal form. However, to get six decimal places you need to use [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html), as follows

```
 NumberForm[MatrixPower[N@P, 500], 6]
```

Or, you can wait to apply `N` until after the matrix power is calculated:

```
NumberForm[ MatrixPower[P, 500] // N, 6]
```